# How can I continue along an If statement in PHP?

Tags: php

Say I had a bunch of if statements.

Say one of them resolved and the code in it ran. Can I make it so that if I had some other condition that fails, it exits that if block, BUT, continues checking the rest of the statements.
E.g.

```
if(condition){

}elseif(condition2){
  //If this code runs, but there are some more conditions within it that fail. 
  //I want the code to continue but
  //continue checking condition3 and condition4. Not exiting the whole block with 
  //continue, nor do I want it to start again.

}elseif(condition3){

}elseif(condition4){

}else{

}
```

I hope this makes some sort of sense.

Comment: Change the `elseif`s to just `if`s?

Comment: Yes, but I might not want it to run condition4 if condition3 passes.

Comment: Then you need to adjust your logic accordingly.  Organize your if's and elseif's according to which conditions you want to run depending on which other conditions are true.  Provide more details because your original question isn't clear enough

Comment: If condition2 passes and it runs that code. Inside that code is another if statement which if fails, I want it to exit that particular code block and continue checking condition3 and condition4 as if it had failed condition2.

Comment: I guess I could incorporate that extra if statement into condition2, but it won't look pretty!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't exactly know what your goal is, but you could maybe use the switch(true) trick and don't call break; if you want to go further with checking cases. Heres is some sample pseudo code.

```
switch(true) {
  case <cond1>:
    <some action>
    break; // breaks the switch      
  case <cond2>:
    if (<cond2_1>) {
       <some action when cond2_1 is true>
       break; // breaks the switch
    }
    // if <cond2_1> failed, no break; is called, so execution continues with next case
  case <cond3>:
    <some action>
    break;
  default: ...      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply make the code

```
if(condition){
}
if(condition2){
}
if(condition3){
}
if(condition4){
}
```

This will check each condition and run each one independently if the condition is true.